# Is the light of Genesis the light John was talking about?

Tags: genesis, gospel-of-john, light

In my search of the truth regarding the true identity of Jesus Christ I have come to discover two verses that talk about the light. According to Saint John the **light** was **Jesus Christ** who came into the world.

**John 1:6-8**

> There was a man sent from God, whose name was John. He came as a witness, to bear witness about the light, that all might believe through him. He was not the light, but came to bear witness about the light.

It's clear from the verse above that the light is a person and this person , John was sent to bear witness to him. This person or the **light** is the **Lord Jesus Christ**, that is why John is saying he was not the light , which means someone else was that light.

Let's go back to Genesis and see what Moses told us about the same **light**

**Genesis 1:3**

> And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. And God saw that the light was good. And God separated the light from the darkness.

There is a very huge parallel between the light of Genesis and the light of John, In Genesis, God separated the light from the darkness while in John men hated the light(Jesus Christ) and loved the darkness(the devil and his works). Could this light in Genesis be the same light John was talking about in the Gospels?
Could the separation of light from darkness have a deeper meaning?

Comment: The site is not open to personal teaching or to personal searching for truth. The site exists to academically comment (in a _comparative_ manner) on 'Christianity' as such. I have voted to close the question as it is not addressed to (nor is it seeking comparative information about) any particular group within self-identifying 'Christianity'.

Comment: It might work better on the Hermeneutics Stack Exchange site.  But, anyway, IMO the light in Genesis 1:2 is a type of Christ. But Christ is **not** "the light" in John 1:9; rather he is "the true light", meaning the light in Genesis 1:2 is _not_ the _true_ light, but a picture or type.  The anti-type is Christ, the Light of the World.

Comment: @AndrewShanks Yes, In him was life. And _the Life_ was the light of the world. The light of creation or the light of nature is not the True Light. The eternal Life, which was with the Father . . . . .  is the true light which was . . . .  'manifested'.

Comment: @NigelJ Amen to that.

Comment: @NigelJ, the light in Genesis is not the light of the sun, the sun was created on the fourth day